# stopping parser when error found in semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I wish to stop a token parser when the semantic action code finds a problem.

> IF x > 10

is syntactically correct, but if x does not exist the the parser should stop

The grammar rule and semantic action look like this

```
    condition
        =   ( tok.identifier >> tok.oper_ >> tok.value )
            [
                boost::phoenix::bind( &cRuleKit::AddCondition, &myRulekit, 
                        boost::spirit::_1, boost::spirit::_2, boost::spirit::_3 )
            ]
        ;
```

So now I add a check for the existence of the identifier

```
    condition
        =   ( tok.identifier[boost::bind(&cRuleKit::CheckIdentifier, &myRulekit, ::_1, ::_3 ) ] 
               >> tok.oper_ >> tok.value )
            [
                boost::phoenix::bind( &cRuleKit::AddCondition, &myRulekit,
                      boost::spirit::_1, boost::spirit::_2, boost::spirit::_3 )
            ]
        ;
```

This works!

I am not thrilled by the elegance.  The grammar syntax is now hard to read and mixing use of boost::bind and boost::phoenix::bind is terribly confusing.

How can I improve it?  I would like to get at the 'hit' parameter from phoenix::bind so that I can do the check inside cRuleKit::AddCondition() and so keep the grammar and actions seperate and avoid using boost::bind.

---

The answer is to use the placeholder _pass

```
    condition
        =   ( tok.identifier >> tok.oper_ >> tok.value )
            [
                boost::phoenix::bind( &cRuleKit::AddCondition, &myRulekit, 
                        boost::spirit::_pass, boost::spirit::_1, boost::spirit::_2, boost::spirit::_3 )
            ]
        ;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spirit has a special value you can use in a semantic action to make the parse fail. It's called `_pass` and you should set it to `false`.

From some of my code:

```
variable_reference_impl_[_pass = lookup_symbol_(_1, false)][_val = _1]
```

in this case, lookup_symbol is a Phoenix functor that returns `true` if the symbol is found, `false` if not.